# Dynamic Typing without duck typing?

Tags: duck-typing, dynamic-typing

I'm used to dynamic typing meaning checking for type info of object/non object oriented structure at runtime and throwing some sort of type error, ie if it quacks like a duck its a duck. Is there a different type of dynamic typing (please go into details).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely. Duck-typing is an idiom which says that the type of a value at this moment in time is based on the fields and methods that it has right now. Dynamic typing just says that types are associated with run-time values, not with static variables and parameters. There is a difference between the two, and you can use the latter without the former.

For example, if you programmed in PHP and limited yourself to the basic types without using OO, then you would be using dynamic typing without using duck-typing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example?  are you simply saying that type checking at runtime is dynamic typing, while checking based on testing the existence of methods and properties of objects is called duck typing? i.e., would you say that the difference between the two has to do with *objects*?  In both cases (non-duck dynamic and duck typing), it looks like the compatibility of certain operations (method call, addition, etc.) with the input values is checked at runtime; is that right?  the only difference is that duck typing concerns objects, and that dynamic typing is more general, right?

Comment: @EOL: Yes, type checking is dynamic typing (which should really be called 'dynamic checking', checking for property existence is duck typing. The 'concerns objects' thing is a bit vague to say that it's correct, but I think we're both on the same page.

Comment: Thanks!  I now see better the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

No, dynamic typing is when values have type but variables do not, so most type checking is done at runtime. So, basically, if the value walks or quacks like a duck, it's a duck, else an error is thrown. Duck typing really just describes a feature of dynamic typing that ensures it will be typesafe (i.e. a method will only run if variable `foo`'has the right attribute or can execute that method).

Comment: That's incorrect.  It doesn't check the type, only that the type can do some operator X or has some attribute Y.  If you call, say, toString() on a variable, then if it is an object and it implements a toString() method, then it will be called, otherwise, you get an error.  But many types could fulfill this requirement.